# In classification, how do you validate the model in case of imbalanced data set?

Tags: validation, machine-learning, deep-learning, classification

I’m kind of a beginner in machine learning and trying to solve a classification problem. I’m working on a very unbalanced (sequential) data set (only 2% positives out of 20k records) and I'm using LSTM/GRUs to model in python using tensorflow.

This is what I do:
Load the data.
Split the data set into 3 data sets :
A for Training (70%)
B for Validating (15%)
C for Testing (15%);
For each data set (A, B, C), do an over-sampling on positive class in order to increase the percentage of positives from 2% to 30%. This gives me 3 new datasets which are more balanced: A’, B’, C’

Then I train my model with the data set A’ using GRU.

My Objective: Get highest F score on my test set C (Are there any better metrics? From what I've seen, F score depends on data distribution i.e. how skewed the data is. If my actual negatives to positives ratio increases then precision  decreases (due to increase in False negatives) though recall more or less remains the same; and so my overall F score goes down)

My questions are:

Can I use cross entropy as my cost function while training ? (I am not altering the cost function to be more sensitive to false positives since I have already over sampled my positives )

Which data set do I have to use for validation ? B or B’ ? and what metric should I use to plot the validation learning curve to know the point where my model is over fitting? (Currently I am using accuracy on both A’ (train) and B’ (validation) to see if there is any over fitting. But it seems accuracy on B’ and f score on B doesn't correlate much. Because ultimately I want good f score on C which means I need the model which gives good f score on B)

Thanks in advance for your time! 
Regards.

Comment: For sure, you should measure the 'accuracy' (or any other metric) in the unbalanced datasets and not on the more balanced ones. This way, you can measure the models performance on real data.

Comment: yes.. makes sense.. but my only problem in that case is can I compare the metrics on A (balanced) and B'(imbalanced) and plot those two find if there is any overfitting or not..

Answer (score 1):

(The following is more a long comment than an complete answer - I need to think about this. I hope I'll find the time to update it this evening / tomorrow)

### Which set should be the test set?

We are using a test set to estimate the real score (error / accuracy / F1-score / recall / precision / ...), hence the score we would get if we tested the model on all possible samples (that would be an extraordinary huge amount of samples; e.g. if you received 32x32 px grayscale images it would be 256^1024 \approx  10^2466).

Hence you take C for testing, not C'.

### Which set should be the validation set?

We are using a validation set to not overfit on the test set. Usually for early stopping. If the score is the optimization objective, it should be B (not B'). If the score is something different, you might want to think about how both go hand in hand (e.g. when the optimization objective gets better, does the score also become better?). If they do not go hand in hand in many cases, you should adjust the optimization objective.

You have the F1 score and are thinking about using cross entropy as the optimization objective. Cross entropy ignores the class, hence you balance the classes.

edit: Thinking about it, I would take F1 score on B as a stopping criterion. Other choices might be valid, too, but this seems to make most sense as the F1 score should be maximized

### Which set should be used the training set?

If you take A you will have the problem that your network learns to always predict the more common class. Hence you have to take A'.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Martin. I am just wondering if I could you plot f score on B and use that for early stopping i.e. I will save the model where I get the best f score on B. What are the other options to plot on B? Same cross entropy? Does this make sense? Because I am training/optimizing for cross entropy on balanced A' and plotting the same cross entropy as my validation curve on imbalanced B.

Comment: So, broadly, I am thinking if optimising my objective function i.e. cross entropy on A' and plot a validation curve for early stopping (and save that model) is same as optimising f1 score on C!! If the answer is yes, then I fell I am done..

Comment: @msa: Optimizing for cross entropy on A' is not the same as optimizing F1 on C. The question is if it is only an academic difference which and both would lead to similar models or if the trained models are actually very different. I can't really answer that (but I expanded my answer as promised)

Comment: Thanks for you comment! I have plotted f1 score on B and results are some what surprising to me. The curve (f1 score on B) doesn't really come down.. and at the same time it is very unstable even after training for many epochs! After 20 odd epochs, I can still see quite a bit variation in f1 score and it is not settling at some value.. In my case it is varying from 0.75 to 0.85 which I think is huge.. May be it is due to the fact that I am optimising for my cross entropy on A' which is more balanced and B is very unbalanced...   Your insights will be very helpful on this!

Comment: I can share my plots (precision, recall and f1 score on Training A' and Validation B) if necessary..